# Combining user tables from 3 php applications

Tags: php, mysql, join, authentication

I have 3 php applications I need to combine the user tables. I want to make it a seamless login process for users. All apps will be hosted on the same domain, cookies can be set to anything required. All 3 apps are running from the same database.

The current user tables have some identical fields and some not. The combined table would be 58 fields.

One table has a different 'id' primary key to the other 2.

There is no data in any application yet as they are a new project. All users will be created by us not via a self-service registration page.

I've searched through the php code for all instances of when each of the tables are called but it isn't clear exactly what would need to be changed should I create a new table with all fields required for each app. Identifying the 'id' is particularly difficult.

Any thoughts on best approach, workarounds ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Its not entirely clear what your actual question is. Perhaps you could show the table definitions.  

As for a solution for the different table definitions, you may want to look into using a view? That way the applications could be using their own view to a shared table.

Comment: I have 3 php applications that each have their own user management/login control. I would like to be able to login once, to app 1 for example and then be able to click on app 2 & 3 and not have to log in again. The issue I am having with using views is that one of the apps uses a primary key of UID whilst the others use ID. I'm not overly familiar with views so no doubt I'm not getting it right.

Comment: I do not have that experience either, so I can only talk about the principle.  I would say that you might be able to create a table that contains both an ID and GUID and provide a view for each application only showing the relevant columns and use the right column names. Especially if the table is indeed read-only from the viewpoint of these applications (and will be managed outside of them), this should be feasible.

Comment: If I create a new table with all columns in existing 3 tables, create views to this table, how do I map (if that's the right word) the UID column to look at the ID column of the new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment before, I think you could solve the problem by introducing one  shared table and provide each application with its own view.

The shared table would then store all the fields needed. Based on the information in this question, this means it stores both an integer ID and a unique identifier. The views maps the columns of the table to the columns that are required by the respective applications.

Now, the second question is how you achieve this mapping. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with MySQL. So let me first try in T-SQL / MS SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [ID] [int] primary key,
    [GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE VIEW Users1 (ID, UserName)
AS SELECT ID, UserName FROM Users
GO

CREATE VIEW Users2 ([GUID], [UserName])
AS SELECT [GUID],[UserName] FROM Users
GO

CREATE VIEW Users3 ([UID], [UserName])
AS SELECT [GUID],[UserName] FROM Users
GO
```

You can also rename the column names in the create view statement, which means that there is no problem if different applications have a different name for a column (e.g.: pwd or password). I have done this in VIEW Users3, where the UID column maps to the GUID column of the actual table.

However, I just realized there is one caveat. I do not see how this works if two or more applications expect the users table to have the same name.

As for MySQL: it seems that most of this T-SQL code should also work for MySQL, except for the table definition I think. See here for how to create a view in MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Let me know if this helped :)